# Convert Oracle outer join to SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle

I'm having trouble converting this Oracle SQL to SQL server.

This is the query:

```
    SELECT CM.ModuleID,
           CM.ModuleDescription,
           CM.ImageIndex,
            CASE
             WHEN CMAC.ClassID IS NULL THEN
              'N'
             ELSE
              'Y'
           END AS Checked
      FROM APP_MODULES         CM,
           APP_PROFILE         CMAP,
           APP_PROFILE_CLASS   CMAC
      WHERE 1 = 1
       AND CM.ParentModuleID IS NULL
       AND CMAP.ProfileID(+) = CMAC.ProfileID
       AND CM.ModuleID = CMAC.ModuleID(+)
       AND CMAC.ProfileID(+) = P_ProfileID
       AND CM.Activated = 'Y'
     ORDER BY CM.Ordem;
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please read [ask].  First off, (+) is old, oracle-specific syntax for an outer join.  You definitely need to change that.

Comment: In addition to @OldPrrogrammer sound advice, I don't understand the need for the WHERE 1 = 1 condition.

Comment: @rontornambe Such a condition is often due to a fitler-builder. You can write a query with `WHERE 1=1 <FILTERS>`, and replace a filter with `AND Condition1 AND Condition2 AND ...`, having any number of conditions. This way the filter builder can be very simple (it doesn't have to generate an actual where clause) flexible (you can have other 'hard-coded' where conditions), and it usually won't affect performance, since such a condition is mostly ignored by the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work in SQL Server:

```
SELECT CM.ModuleID,
       CM.ModuleDescription,
       CM.ImageIndex,
        CASE
         WHEN CMAC.ClassID IS NULL THEN
          'N'
         ELSE
          'Y'
       END AS Checked
  FROM APP_MODULES         CM,
       LEFT JOIN APP_PROFILE_CLASS CMAC 
            ON(CMAC.ProfileID = P_ProfileID AND CM.ModuleID = CMAC.ModuleID)
       LEFT JOIN APP_PROFILE CMAP
            ON(CMAP.ProfileID = CMAC.ProfileID)
  WHERE 1 = 1
   AND CM.ParentModuleID IS NULL
   AND CM.Activated = 'Y'
 ORDER BY CM.Ordem;
```